# SQL select 3 hour avg

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

i got this table:

```
MariaDB [table]> 
select insert_time, host_id, tx 
from host_daily 
where host_id = 2 
order by insert_time desc 
limit 24;

+---------------------+---------+------------+
| insert_time         | host_id | tx         |
+---------------------+---------+------------+
| 2016-02-06 14:00:00 |       2 | 9676875156 |
| 2016-02-06 13:00:00 |       2 | 9671544048 |
| 2016-02-06 12:00:00 |       2 | 9669464371 |
| 2016-02-06 11:00:00 |       2 | 9667087098 |
| 2016-02-06 10:00:00 |       2 | 9665014071 |
| 2016-02-06 09:00:00 |       2 | 9662931956 |
| 2016-02-06 08:00:00 |       2 | 9660874138 |
| 2016-02-06 07:00:00 |       2 | 9658624162 |
| 2016-02-06 06:00:00 |       2 | 9656555329 |
| 2016-02-06 05:00:00 |       2 | 9654443169 |
| 2016-02-06 04:00:00 |       2 | 9651362676 |
| 2016-02-06 03:00:00 |       2 | 9648531733 |
| 2016-02-06 02:00:00 |       2 | 9633368883 |
| 2016-02-05 23:00:00 |       2 | 9464826179 |
| 2016-02-05 22:00:00 |       2 | 9363099844 |
| 2016-02-05 21:00:00 |       2 | 9270841166 |
| 2016-02-05 20:00:00 |       2 | 9140988502 |
| 2016-02-05 19:00:00 |       2 | 9022460285 |
| 2016-02-05 18:00:00 |       2 | 8925920799 |
| 2016-02-05 17:00:00 |       2 | 8825711136 |
| 2016-02-05 16:00:00 |       2 | 8802081092 |
| 2016-02-05 15:00:00 |       2 | 8755784419 |
+---------------------+---------+------------+
```

It's not obvious, but it's possible that some hours are missing. E.g. between 23 and 2 o'clock. If possible I'd like to fill this missing hours with 0.
Now I want to select the three hour averages for the last week, but I don't seem to get the query right. I am trying and modifying this query for a while:

```
select 
    n.n as id, 
    host_id,
    avg(tx),
    insert_time + interval 3 * n.n hour as 'from',
    insert_time + interval 3 * (n.n + 1) hour as 'to'
from (SELECT  0 AS n
          UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
          UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
          UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
          UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
          UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
          UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
          UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
          UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 
     ) n 
left join host_daily
     on n.n = hour(insert_time) div 3
where host_id = 2 
  and insert_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR group by n.n;
```

resulting in:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | host_id | avg(tx)         | from                | to                  |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 |       2 | 9672627858.3333 | 2016-02-07 00:00:00 | 2016-02-07 03:00:00 |
|  3 |       2 | 9665011041.6667 | 2016-02-06 18:00:00 | 2016-02-06 21:00:00 |
|  2 |       2 | 9658684543.0000 | 2016-02-06 12:00:00 | 2016-02-06 15:00:00 |
|  1 |       2 | 9651445859.3333 | 2016-02-06 06:00:00 | 2016-02-06 09:00:00 |
|  0 |       2 | 9605672722.3333 | 2016-02-06 00:00:00 | 2016-02-06 03:00:00 |
|  7 |       2 | 9366255729.6667 | 2016-02-06 18:00:00 | 2016-02-06 21:00:00 |
|  6 |       2 | 9029789862.0000 | 2016-02-06 12:00:00 | 2016-02-06 15:00:00 |
|  5 |       2 | 9019970953.0000 | 2016-02-06 06:00:00 | 2016-02-06 09:00:00 |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Would someone be so kind to point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**
maintaining example integrity, by editing the query results to the expected result, returning from a 24 hour view.

Comment: 3 hours avg meaning  `(1,2,3) - (2,3,4) - (3,4,5) - (4,5,6) ... (21,22,23)` ? Can you include you expected result with that sample data?   Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 
 Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: 3 hours avg means that I want to select the first three hours returning of the selected week. In the example it would be from 15:00 to 17:00 and returning the avg of tx[0] 8755784419 + tx[1] 8802081092 + tx[2] 8825711136 as one row, the next row starting from 18:00 to 20:00 and so on. Probably as you described now where I finished typing.

Comment: In the latest [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/), you could replace all that `UNION` by a magic table: `seq_0_to_23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to round each time down to a three hour period.  Assuming that you have at least one record for each three hour period, you can just use rounding:

```
select from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(insert_time)/(60*60*3))*60*60*3) as timestart,
       host_id,
       sum(tx) / 3
from host_daily hd
group by from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(insert_time)/(60*60*3))*60*60*3), hostid
order by 1, 2;
```

This sort of assumes that you want the missing values treated as 0.  If not, then use `avg(tx)` instead.

If this is still missing rows, you can add them in with whatever value you want for the periods when *all* data is missing.  Your question is vague about what to include in that case.

Comment: I'd like to treat the missing values as 0, because they are machine outages. If the machine would spin up at 13:45 there would be an average value for 14:00. Sorry for being unclear, I'll try your suggestion out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. But you should avoid the hardcoded devider. It's not guaranteed that there are 2 elements to be grouped with the first timestamp. For clarification example http://pastebin.com/raw/0HNqPrVX